# Possible to use Data Factory to extract all Azure Active Directory users?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory

Microsoft has the tutorial showing how to use Data Factory to extract Office 365 data, but that seems to only extract Outlook email information?

Is there a way to use Data Factory (and a tutorial hopefully) to connect to Azure AD and extract all the Active Directory users?  Microsoft Graph API has the commands to do that, but I wasn't clear if that was the only way or if Data Factory can connect to it directly (like the O365 connector it has)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Microsoft has the tutorial showing how to use Data Factory to extract Office 365 data, but that seems to only extract Outlook email information?

According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-office-365),not only email information,there are many other information such as address book contacts, calendar events, user information, mailbox settings, and so on.

So you can get user information which contains `aboutMe`,`companyName`,etc. when you choose `BasicDataSet_v0.User_v1` in dataset.(All properties you can get,please refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0))

By the way,your tenant admin need to opt-in to Microsoft Graph data connect if you do this.And there is no AAD connector.

[image: officedataset]

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you, I did not properly understand the data sets being displayed there!!!

Comment: Does opt-in to Microsoft Graph data connect have costs?

Answer (score 1):

I used Azure Logic Apps and got through Azure AD group (get members) then used Office 365 Connector to Get Manager there is also another option get direct reports. If you are using Logic apps please make sure to turn the pagination on so you get all users.

This is were I started but once I get going I was able to figure it out myself
https://eax360.com/query-azure-active-directory-using-graph-api-logic-apps/