# Possible to use Azure Synapse Analytics to extract all Azure Active Directory users?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-synapse

I am new to this and struggling to understand if this is possible. I want to extract Azure AD users and use this data to create organisational charts but was told to see if it is possible to gather the data through Azure and then parse it into Power BI or something similar to gain this effect.

If anyone have any idea how to do this or what other tools I should use instead, I would be grateful.

Comment: For this you can use the Graph API. You can find many tutorials for it on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Microsoft documentation,not only email information,there are many other information such as address book contacts, calendar events, user information, mailbox settings, and so on.

So you can get user information which contains aboutMe,companyName,etc. when you choose BasicDataSet_v0.User_v1 in dataset.(All properties you can get,please refer to this documentation)

By the way,your tenant admin need to opt-in to Microsoft Graph data connect if you do this.And there is no AAD connector.

[Possible to use Data Factory to extract all Azure Active Directory users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62682926/possible-to-use-data-factory-to-extract-all-azure-active-directory-users)

You can even use Web activity to get that data from REST API (Graph API)